# NDSolve limitation?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or if there is some implicit limitation on what `NDSolve` can do. My code is,

```
NDSolve[{x + h[x] (1 + h''[x]) == 0, h[-10] == 1, h[10] == 1}, h, {x, -10, 10}]
```

Mathematica 10.2 just gives me the same thing back, without solving (I'm expecting an interpolating function). I'm new to the game, so not sure what the problem is. When I simplify the equation it solves it perfectly. Is there something in the form that cannot be solved?

N.B. My actual equation is much longer and uglier, this is just a MWE that I cut it down to

Comment: @mikado, thanks. The documentation says both are acceptable, but that your suggestion solves for `h[x]` instead of `h`; I'm not sure what that means, but it shouldn't be the source of the problem.

Comment: you are quite right.  However, in V11.0.0 it fails complaining (it appears) about `ComplexInfinity` at x==-10.

Comment: You might investigate the behaviour by specifying boundary conditions somewhere else e.g. h[0]==1, h'[0]==1 gives some sort of solution.

Comment: Mmmm, interesting, thanks for that! I'll have a look.

Comment: In V10.2, I get a mess of errors, just as @mikado mentions: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5Av91.png

Comment: @bjorne Out of curiosity, what is the original problem that this MWE is a shorter or manageable version of?

Comment: @drN, there are a few versions depending on different models, parameters and BCs, but one example is `4 h[x]^2 (-0.7 - x^2/2 + h[x])^3 ((1.4 + x^2) Derivative[1][h][x] + 
    2 (Derivative[1][h][
         x] (-h[x] + 2 (1.4 + x^2) Derivative[1][h][x]) + 
       h[x] (-5 + 8. h[x] - 4 Derivative[1][h][x]^2 - 
          2. (1.4 + x^2 - 2. h[x]) (h^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x]))) == 
 30 (1.4 + x^2 - 2 h[x]) h[
   x]^3 (1.4 + x^2 + 
    2 h[x]) (2 h[x] + (-0.7 - x^2/2 + h[x]) (1 + 1.6 h[x]))`

Comment: @bjorne Nonlinear differential equation.  What exactly is it modelling? I worked iwith nonlinear partial differential equations, so I ask out of interest.

Comment: @drN, it's a multiphase flow problem with a free surface `h[x]`. The nonlinearity is from the inertial terms in N-S. With some work you can reduce the system to some weakly coupled ODEs, like that one for the free surface and then some others for the pressure etc.

Comment: @bjorne Thank you.  Would you mind including a citation of this work.  I am curious to know of its analytical development.

Comment: @drN I don't have any off hand, I'm modelling the problem from scratch, but a google on Stokes flow, free surface, asymptotics should provide some similar maths

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Often when there is a problem with the `"ShootingMethod"` method, it's to do with the automatically chosen starting initial conditions.  Since the method is based on [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html), having a good starting point is sometimes crucial to finding a solution.

My personal feeling is that `NDSolve` should warn the user that it was the shooting method that failed and that either the user might specify `"StartingInitialConditions"` manually or that the ODE might have problems.  (It probably cannot determine which.)

Shooting high and low, I found two solutions:

```
{sol1} = NDSolve[{ode = x + h[x] (1 + h''[x]) == 0, h[-10] == 1, h[10] == 1},
  h, {x, -10, 10},
  Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {h[-10] == 1, h'[-10] == 10.}}]

{sol2} = NDSolve[{x + h[x] (1 + h''[x]) == 0, h[-10] == 1, h[10] == 1},
  h, {x, -10, 10},
  Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {h[-10] == 1, h'[-10] == -10.}}]

Plot[h[x] /. {sol1, sol2} // Evaluate, {x, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

*Update*:
Perhaps a nicer way of manually finding starting points:

```
Manipulate[
 Quiet@ListLinePlot[
   NDSolveValue[{x + h[x] (1 + h''[x]) == 0, h[-10] == 1, h'[-10] == (hp0 = hp)},
    h, {x, -10, 10}],
   GridLines -> {None, {1}}, GridLinesStyle -> Red,
   PlotLabel -> $MessageList, PlotRange -> {{-10.1, 10.1}, Automatic}],
 {hp, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So a starting initial condition of `h'[-10] == -5.98` should be good.  Similarly one can find another near `5.86`.  The values are saved in the global variable `hp0`.  Starting values of `h'[-10]` near zero fail to integrate and emit messages (`NDSolveValue:ndsz`, i.e., a stiffness or singularity error).  The use of `Quiet` keeps the `Manipulate` from getting red-faced, and `$MessageList` lets you know the message name.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks, this looks reasonable. I'll see if it solves my actual problem.

Answer (score 4):

We can approximate the function, with a function iteration:

```
facc = ((-i - f[i])/f[i]);
f[-10] = 1;
dt = 1/1000;
Table[f[i + dt] = (1/2) facc (dt)^2, {i, -10, 10 - dt, dt}];
```

Note that `h[10]` is ignored here:
For plotting purposes, I'm limiting the domain to `{-10,0}`

```
ListPlot[Table[{i, f[i]}, {i, -10, 10, 1/10}], Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large]
```

With

```
dt=1/10
```

[image]

```
dt=1/100
```

[image]

```
dt=1/1000
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[Table[{i, f[i]}, {i, -10, 0, dt}][[1 ;; 50]], Joined -> True,
```

PlotRange -> All]

[image]

So we can clearly see that as `dt` becomes infinitesimally small, we reach complexinfinity $\frac{1}{0}$ closer and closer to $x=-10$.

Conclusion: the ODE is malformed.

Comment: +1. Thanks for the insight. I don't really see how I've enforced four conditions (there are two boundary conditions on a second-oeder ODE, this is a standard BVP). I'm also struggling to get your code working, it runs really slowly because it does everything symbolically so has these really long fractions. I also don't really understand what your iteration scheme is. A standard FD scheme should have two extra terms, like `+2f[i]-f[i-dt]` with an extra initial condition of, say, `f[-10-dt]=1`

Comment: You're right there are only two constraints, kind of rushed the explanation. I'm using the fact that `f[x]=1/2 f''[x] x^2` to define the function. I tried to get it working with a normal iteration function, but didn't see how to do so right now. This is certainly slower to compute, but it works.

Comment: @bjorne Regardless, my answer is superseded my michael-e2