# Boundary value problem error: ComplexInfinity

Tags: differential-equations

I'm trying to solve an ODE with boundary values:

```
NDSolve[{(1 + Derivative[1][θ][ρ]^2) (3 θ'[ρ] Tan[θ[ρ]] - 4 Tanh[ρ]) + 
    Tanh[ρ] Tan[θ[ρ]] θ''[ρ] == 0, θ[0] == 0.5, θ[2] == Pi/2}, θ, {ρ, 0, 2}]
```

and getting the following error

```
Infinity::indet: "Indeterminate expression 0.\ ComplexInfinity encountered."
```

For some boundary values it works, especially if the start and end points are close together. As the points are moved apart, it starts to fail. Any idea why it is failing?

Comment: I think this is a similar problem, which has a well-explained solution http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124456/36788

Comment: @mikado In this case, the OP omitted an important clue, "NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at ρ == 0.`."  The fact that this happens at the initial condition and not somewhere in the interior of the interval of integration suggests a singularity at `ρ == 0`.  Indeed, the coefficient of `θ''[ρ]` vanishes because `Tanh[0] == 0`. Since `NDSolve` begins by solving for `θ''[ρ]`, and the `1/Tanh[ρ]` turns into `Coth[ρ]`, this is the source of the `ComplexInfinity`. [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91854) has a similar problem.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I thought the same, but I checked it away from theta = 0. Try for example:     `NDSolve[{(1 + 
       Derivative[
           1][\[Theta]][\[Rho]]^2) (3 \[Theta]'[\[Rho]] Tan[\[Theta][\
\[Rho]]] - 4 Tanh[\[Rho]]) + 
    Tanh[\[Rho]] Tan[\[Theta][\[Rho]]] \[Theta]''[\[Rho]] == 
   0, \[Theta][0.1] == 0.5, \[Theta][2] == 
   Pi/2 - 0.1}, \[Theta], {\[Rho], 0.1, 2}]`

Comment: @mikado Thanks for the link but when I try the shooting method manually, it doesn't work. There's seems to be no initial gradient for which it works.

Comment: @DamienJuan Yeah, starting at `0` is one problem, but as you seemed to notice, starting at `0.1` leads to a different problem.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm not sure what you mean, for me both give the ComplexInfinity error.

Comment: @DamienJuan When you start integration at `ρ == 0`, the infinity is "your fault", because one gets the initial value for `θ''[0]` by dividing by `Tanh[0]`; when you start at `ρ == 0.1`, somewhere down the line the shooting method tries `{θ[0.1], θ'[0.1]} == {0., 0.}` as an initial condition which also leads to infinity for `θ''[0]` from the factor `Tan[θ[ρ]]` in front of the second derivative.  That's the fault of `NDSolve`. I suppose it tries `{0., 0.}` because it cannot satisfy the BCs with `θ[0.1] == 0.5`.